# Passing model fields into functions as parameters to create other fields django

Tags: django, django-models

I following up with my question [Creating new objects under specific parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962553/creating-new-objects-under-specific-parameters) . I was trying to find out how to write functions into my django models to create default values on fields. I know how to do that, but now would like to take it a step further by adding parameters to the functions and using previous fields as the parameters. So far I have tried the following and each have given their own error messages when I try and migrate them.

```py
class NewTest(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def num(score): # Want the score parameter to be the score field
        new_num = score
        return new_num
    last_score = models.IntegerField(default=num(score))
Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'IntegerField'


class NewTest(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def num(self):
        new_num = self.score
        return new_num
    last_score = models.IntegerField(default=num(self))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined


class NewTest(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def num():
        new_num = self.score
        return new_num
    last_score = models.IntegerField(default=num)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Does anybody know how to do this, or know where there is documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Django's model field `default` callable can't actually be an instance method. Due to  how this callable is used in migrations it must be serializable for migrations, e.g. in the migrations you'll see a reference to the path of the function, such as `default="my_app.models.my_callable_default"`.

The way I've seen other solve this is to override the models `save` method to check those fields and set the default value there.

```
class NewTest(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # Check for create
            self.last_score = self.score
        else:
            # Get the existing score from the database, because this instance has been modified
            score_from_db = NewTest.objects.values("score").get(pk=self.pk)["score"]
            self.last_score = self.score
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Continue with save as normal
```

This solution overrides the `save` method of your model to assign another fields value to the `last_score` field during creation, and if it's an update it will pull the existing object from the database to get the last score (I'm not sure if this is what you are after).  The `if not self.pk` is used to check if the current save is being called for a new object (create), or an existing object (update), because the database assigns the primary key during creation.

Comment: Glad to help @Rajan, could you vote on this answer to mark it as the solution :)

Comment: You need a reputation of 15 or more to cast votes, so unfortunately I can't. I just made an account recently but when I have enough reputation I will certainly vote for it. But thanks for your help I really appreciate it!